# How to get an expression for Sum of first n terms of the following series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$1^2+2\cdot2^2+3^2+2\cdot4^2+5^2+2\cdot6^2+\ldots$

I have tried it a number of ways

First way is I split the series into halves like this
$ ( 1 ^ 2 +  2 ^ 2 + 3 ^ 2 + 4 ^ 2 + 5 ^ 2 + 6 ^ 2 +...) + (2 ^ 2 + 4 ^ 2 + 6 ^ 2 +... ) $

Took last term of first sum as 2n and last term of second sum as n and I am getting something like $ \frac{1}{6}(2n(2n+1)(8n+5)) $

Another way I did this $ 2(1 ^ 2 +  2 ^ 2 + 3 ^ 2 + 4 ^ 2 + 5 ^ 2 + 6 ^ 2 +...) - (1 ^ 2 + 3 ^ 2 + 5 ^ 2  +...) 
 $

And i get $ 4n^2(n+1) $

But my textbook mentions

Sum when last term is even :
$ \frac{n(n+1)^2}{2} $

Sum when last term is odd :
$ \frac{(n+1)n^2}{2} $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be careful with the final terms, instead of just writing $\ldots$.

If the last term is $2 \times (2n)^2$, your sum is
$$  \sum_{k=1}^{2n} k^2 +  \sum_{k=1}^n (2k)^2 $$
but if the last term is $(2n+1)^2$, the sum is
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} k^2 + \sum_{k=1}^n (2k)^2 $$

Answer (score 4):

We will use the following equality

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6\;.\;\;\color{blue}{(1)}\qquad$ [Here is a proof of (1)](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/)

If $\,n\,$ is odd ( that is $\,n=2a-1\,,\,$ where $\,a\in\Bbb N$ ) , then

$\begin{align}S_n&=1^2\!+2\!\cdot\!2^2\!+3^2\!+2\!\cdot\!4^2\!+5^2\!+2\!\cdot\!6^2\!+\ldots+2\!\cdot\!(n\!-\!1)^2\!+n^2\!=\\[3pt]
&=\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2+\!\!\sum\limits_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2}(2k)^2=\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2+4\!\!\sum\limits_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2}k^2\!\!\!\underset{\overbrace{\text{ by using (1) }}}{=}\\[3pt]
&=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6+4\,\dfrac{\frac{n-1}2\frac{n+1}2n}6=\\[3pt]
&=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6+\dfrac{n(n+1)(n-1)}6=\\[3pt]
&=\dfrac{n(n+1)3n}6=\dfrac{n^2(n+1)}2\;.\end{align}$

Whereas if $\,n\,$ is even ( that is $\,n=2a\,,\,$ where $\,a\in\Bbb N$ ) , then

$\begin{align}S_n&=1^2\!+2\!\cdot\!2^2\!+3^2\!+2\!\cdot\!4^2\!+5^2\!+2\!\cdot\!6^2\!+\ldots+(n\!-\!1)^2\!+2\!\cdot\!n^2\!=\\[3pt]
&=\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n/2}(2k)^2=\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2+4\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n/2}k^2\!\!\!\underset{\overbrace{\text{ by using (1) }}}{=}\\[3pt]
&=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6+4\,\dfrac{\frac n2\frac{n+2}2(n+1)}6=\\[3pt]
&=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6+\dfrac{n(n+1)(n+2)}6=\\[3pt]
&=\dfrac{n(n+1)(3n+3)}6=\dfrac{n(n+1)^2}2\;.\end{align}$